# How can I make the HUD change in different levels? [Unreal Engine]

Tags: unreal-engine4

So I have recently started using Unreal Engine to start game development, and it is going well so far. (I am extremely new by the way, I started yesterday, but I do have programming experience).  I am trying to make a HUD, the problem is, I also made another level, but I do not want the HUD to show up on that level, rather I would like to use another HUD. How can I switch between HUDs depending on the level?

I have tried YouTube but found nothing that answered it specifically.

Thanks in advance, and English is not my first language so I apologize for my bad grammar.

Comment: Please provide what you have tried so far.

Comment: @PLASMAchicken I have tried to make a new game mode and when the new level progresses, the game mode changes, changing the HUD. This did not work for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the level blueprint to display the hud and when u change levels if the other level has a different hud u want to use you can do the same and use the level blueprint to do the same hope this helps.